# How to use Conditionally Formatted Data bars on three leveled grouped rows that are populated with data on the fly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where there are rows grouped at three levels. The data is populated dynamically. Currently, I am able to assign conditionally formatted data bars across the whole column (Col Q). But, I want different colored data bars for each level of rows. See in the picture below, I want data bars for all red colored rows to be in red color (Row 47), data bars for purple colored rows to be in purple color. What I have right now is purple all the way.

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

[image]

This is the code block I have for all the red rows. Somehow, the bar size is not reflective of the value present in the corresponding cell.

```
        Set db = Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress").Cells(delvRow, delv_StatusCell + 1).FormatConditions.AddDatabar()
        db.BarColor.Color = vbRed
        db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuePercent, newvalue:=0
        db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuePercent, newvalue:=100
```

Comment: And how are you adding the data bars currently?

Comment: Selected the whole column Q > Conditional Formatting > Data Bars > Format all cells based on values. From there on, I pretty much left everything default (except the color code)

Comment: Seems like you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: Much to my chagrin, probably yes :/

Comment: Is there a way to just alter the color code of the bar? I know the cell references programatically. I just need that color changed to red from purple.

Comment: I would try the macro recorder. Looks like you need `FormatCondition.BarColor`.

Comment: Why won't this work ~~~~~> Set db = Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress").Cells(delvRow, delv_StatusCell + 15).FormatConditions.AddDatabar()
            db.BarColor.Color = vbYellow

Comment: I was able to make it work (sort of) with the color. But, I lost the ability to reflect the size of the bar based on the percentage value. I saw in an article that you could set the min and max values to the databar via code. I guess I will try that and report.

Comment: See my question above for the latest update. I added minpoint and maxpoint, but it did not seem to have any effect on the size of the bar. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any helpers ...?

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code block to this. I added the format via code. Changed the min and max values.

```
    Cells(delvRow, delv_StatusCell + 1).NumberFormat = "0%"

    Set db = Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress").Cells(delvRow, delv_StatusCell + 1).FormatConditions.AddDatabar()

    db.BarColor.Color = vbRed
    db.MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuenumber, newvalue:=0
    db.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValuenumber, newvalue:=1
```